# Consumir archivo de configuracion dentro de un HTML

Tags: html, configuración

Necesito saber como consumir un archivo de configuracion (con variables dinamicas, dependiendo el entorno donde se utilice) desde un HTML y como debo invocar a esas variables (dentro del codigo html))

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Ejemplo de archivo de configuración:

```
; Enviroment name
ENV_NAME = "DEV"

; Soap Webservices
EX1_WS  = "ACA VA VALOR DE UNA CONSTANTE"
```

Comment: HTML en sí no va a poder hacer nada con eso, vas a necesitar algo como JavaScript o un script en el servidor o algo. ¿Cómo quieres usar los valores que leas del archivo de configuración?

Comment: son URLs que dependen de los ambientes donde se encuentran.

Comment: Eso se entiende en el texto de tu publicación. Mi pregunta es más saber cómo los vas a usar, ¿en PHP para hacer peticiones SOAP? ¿En JavaScript para llamarlos con AJAX? Porque dependiendo de qué es lo que quieras hacer, se consumirán de una manera u otra.

Comment: Si en PHP para llamadas a servicios SOAP. Pero el HTML quiero que ej: El ambiente de desarrollo tenga una variable "google.com" y el ambiente productivo "facebook.com".